# 2011 Macbook Pro with faulty screen running on hdmi no entry / access after upgrade to high sierra

Tags: macbook-pro, display, macos, high-sierra

I have a 2011 MBP which i bought with a faulty screen to use with an external monitor / TV which has all been fine until today. After seeing the upgrade to high sierra reminder everyday and ignoring it i thought i might as well give it a look and told it to go ahead without thinking about the display issue. After the initial restart all i get is a grey no entry sign on my external hdmi display and nothing i do will change that, I tried booting in safe mode by holding the shift key down but with the display open i don't get anything on the TV so no idea whats happening on the broken screen. I tried hitting shift on a wired keyboard after hitting the power button and quickly shutting the lid but again nothing. only if i hit the button and close the lid i get the TV on wight he grey no entry logo. So it looks like i killed my perfectly working laptop in no time. Any advise greatly appreciated.

Comment: The external screen is unrelated to your problem.  The issue is that your MBP will not boot after HS upgrade.  See this post:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/317149/osx-prohibited-symbol-on-boot-high-sierra-update-caused

Comment: Thanks, I just tried a pram reset etc with the lid down and it has booted and is continuing the install to HS, I only got to the select drive and restart when i got the no entry sign so like the other post I'm not sure it would be something like a hardware issue but i will see how far i get?? saying 45mins to continue so time will tell. thanks for the post.

Comment: Looks like a general installer failure, quickest would be reinstalling and restoring from backups